# does an iphone UDID have an integrated checksum

Tags: iphone

Do apple's iPhone / iPad UDID's contain a checksum ?
I'm asking because I'm wondering if it would be possible to add non-existant or "wrong" UDID's to the Devices list at the developer portal.

thanks for your help

sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, the answer is no. Just had one provided by a client and one digit was wrong. We built the app and found it didn't install on the phone. Lesson learned - we now ask for a screenshot of the UDID so we can be sure it is entered correctly.

Comment: wow, haven't thought that this question would be answered one day :) bigga up! thx!